# TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly or TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

Tags: python

I'm writing a calculator for a a bio equation, and part of it is a temperature convertor.

```
T_option = input("Celsius, fahrenheit, or Kelvin? ").lower()
if T_option == "celsius" or T_option == "c":
    T_C = input("Input temperature: ")
    T = (T_C - 273.15)
    print("Temp set to " + str(T) + "K")

elif T_option == "kelvin" or T_option == "k":
    T = input("Input temperature: ")
    print("Temp set to " + str(T) + "K")

elif T_option == "fahrenheit" or T_option == "f":
    T_F = input("Input temperature: ")
    T = ((T_F + 459.67) * 5/9)
    ("Temp set to  " + str(T) + "K")
```

If I choose fahrenheit and enter a number, I get:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly
```

If I choose celsius and enter a number, I get:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'
```

I'm not sure what I've done here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input()` function returns a `str` object. You must convert the string to `float` before using it on math expressions. So,

for celsius:

```
T = (float(T_C) - 273.15)
```

for fahrenheit:

```
T = ((float(T_F) + 459.67) * 5/9)
```

Comment: If you are running a python-2.7, you have to prevent the integer division, turning 5/9 into 5.0/9.0, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is with your input, input() in Python always returns a string. If you want to read in some other type then you need to cast it from a string to that type. In your code you probably want something like:

```
T = float(input("Input temperature: "))
```

This will convert the input (e.g. '0.12') to a float (0.12).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to Python. When I try `T_F = input("Input temperature: ")` , I type for instance 40.5, and then try  `type(T_F)` it says float. Moreover, `T_F*5` works perfectly, so in my shell input seems to return a float.  Is there any reason?

Comment: It shouldn't say float if you do type(T_F).  T_F*5 would work because you can multiply strings by an integer, if you try T_F*5.1 it should give an error. Python has no way of knowing that that input should be a float, so type(T_F) should return something that looks like <class 'str'>

Comment: It says `<type 'float'>` and T_F*5.1 works...Python interpreter version 2.7.6